# How to import/upload multiple json files to Azure Devops Pipeline Releases?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

The following script tries to import multiple json files to Azure DevOps Pipeline Release.

```
$JsonNames = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\path\Downloads\*.json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ($JN in $JsonNames)

{

$token = "PAT"

$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON= Get-Content "C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\$($JN).json"

echo $JSON


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON


}
```

I receive the following error message. I have used the Get Rest API to get a new a new release definition, updated the project and build id but still receive this error message. Is there a way that the script ignores the Artifact ID?

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402962: No artifact version ID is specified corresponding to artifact source 'Test'. Specify 
a valid value and try again.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At line:19 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "B ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: The reason for this question may be that the contents of your JSON file do not conform to the REST API Body format. Could you please provide a sample script? Also, I would like to know the meaning of importing JSON files to release, because depending on your script, what you are doing is updating the releases multiple times with JSON files as the body.

Comment: Hi @albbla91. Please refer to the answer below and try to export a new json file to test . If this issue still exists, can you share the types and settings of artifacts you use?

Comment: Thank you @KevinLu-MSFT, I will try this this weekend and will update you. Sorry for any inconvenience caused on the delay.

Comment: @albbla91. Feel free to let me know the result. If you have any questions, I will still be here to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, when you try to upload the json files to release pipeline, you only need to change the **queueid** and release **Definition ID**.

For example： change queueId and the release id before the release definition name.

```
"downloadInputs":[]},"queueId":227,"demands":

"IntegrateJiraWorkItems":{"$type":"System.String","$value":"false"}},"id":10,"name":"New release pipeline (511)","path":"\\"
```

Although you have to upload release definition json in different projects, you still don’t need to change the **buildid** and **projectid**.

Then the same script will successfully create release.

> VS402962: No artifact version ID is specified corresponding to artifact source 'Test'. Specify
> a valid value and try again

According to the error message, you could check the version of the build artifacts in the  original release pipeline. You need to make sure that the version of the artifacts exists.

[image]